# Accessing same resource from different threads when resource is static

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I have a Dictionary instance that I setup when the application starts. The content of this dictionary doesnt change during the lifespan of the application (as in it never gets modified, only read from).

Will I still have to keep the resource threadsafe?
Will it throw exception when two threads try to access it at the same time even though both are just reading from it and never modifying it?

BR Tomas A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you don't need to lock read-only resources**. The purpose of locking is to check the value of a resource before writing it so that another resource can't change the value between your read and your write.

Comment: Been a while and Im suprised I had to ask this 3 years ago, anyhow thank you very much for your answer, marked it correct and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), you're safe:

> ### Thread Safety
>
> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so,
>   enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration.
>   To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading
>   and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

If you're using .Net 4.5, it would probably make sense to expose the dictionary as an [`IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548.aspx) to help ensure that it is used in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the Dictionary collection here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe